# mysql get result of most frequent value of every post

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I found some similar questions with good answers but i couldnt figure out how to apply this to my specific case.  I have a site where users can rate there favorite post from 1-6. Every number is a different category.

Now i need to know the most frequently votes for every single post. So i need to count every post id and than the most frequent values of every post id.

After that i wanna update every result in another table. (dont know how to figure this out right now i'm not that good with Mysql yet).

this are the two columns where i need to know how often every post exist in post_id  and what is the most frequently voting number of every single post.

just an example of my table (value = voting)

```
value | post_id               
---------------
  3    |   12
  1    |   6
  4    |   13
  2    |   5
  6    |   12
  5    |   6
```

i need the output like this to know which post is mostly votet for which category.

```
post | most voted in this category               
---------------
  1    |   3
  2    |   5
  3    |   6
  4    |   1
  5    |   4
  6    |   6
```

i need this for every post in the table. and than i would need to update every post in another table. i guess i have to do this in a loop.
but im already stuck at the first part.

all i have is this. for the first part.

```
    <?php global $wpdb;

$test = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT posts_id, value, COUNT(posts_id) AS ActionCount
FROM rating_item_entry_value
GROUP BY posts_id
ORDER BY ActionCount DESC'); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($test);
echo '</pre>';
```

and this is the output i get

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 0
            [value] => 5
            [ActionCount] => 7
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 221
            [value] => 3
            [ActionCount] => 3
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 197
            [value] => 5
            [ActionCount] => 2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [posts_id] => 164
            [value] => 3
            [ActionCount] => 1
        )

)
```

for the example.

I have no idea how to do this better, trying a lot but can't figure it out. does anyone has a good solution how to get the most frequent number for every single id? (and maybe how to safe the results in a variable to update every post in another table within a loop?)  thank u so much for any help. regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most frequently means count aggregation and group by frequency. you can map this to your problem:

```
select
    x.amount,
    count(*) as times -- I forgot that row
from
    X x
group by
    x.amount
order by
    count(*) DESC
```

// edit to you mean that

```
select
    post_id,
    value,
    count(*)
from
    your_table
group by
    post_id,
    value
order by
    count(*) desc
```

Comment: thank u so much for ur help Aitch. with your querry i get no now how often a voting value appears in the database. how would i combine this two querries to now how often a voting appears by post (posts_id)??

Comment: edit the answer above. So want to say: Post 3 has a voting of 5 3 time, post 3 has a voting of 4 1 time, etc.

Comment: thanks mate  for your help again.  the only output i get now is  "ARRAY" maybe im just to stupid.   $test = $wpdb->get_results('select
    post_id,
    value,
    count(*)
From
    rating_item_entry_value
group by
    post_id,
    value
order by
    count(*) desc'); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r("$test");
echo '</pre>';

Comment: :) `"$test"` converts the array to a string first: `print_r($test)` is correct

Comment: yihaaaaaaaaaaa  now it works.  you re awesome Aitch  thank u so much mate and have a great week.  btw  one last question if u have time to answer sometime again.   how would i gather and save the results in a variable and save the results for every id into another 2 column table.

Comment: if not necessary, don't save redundant data in the database. everytime sometimes changes, you have to change your snapshot.